# Viewing the tcp/udp ports which are opened by a process on Linux

Tags: linux, networking

Is there any command on Linux available to show which udp/tcp ports are opened by a certain application on Linux. I don't mean netstat, because thats's only showing the open ports.

Presumably, this is a daemon that runs and studying the connections that are coming from some application.

Comment: Can you clarify?  You want to show the open ports belonging to an application - netstat *can* do this, with the -p switch

Comment: Your question is confusing, especially "[...]show which udp/tcp ports _are opened_ by a certain application on Linux. I don't mean netstat, because thats's only _showing the open ports_." Can you clarify ?

Comment: Yeah, but I am interested in the ports an application is trying to open (also the onces that are bounced off by some firewall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command `ss` is used to dump socket statistics and command  `nc` arbitrary TCP and UDP connections and listens

Basically Most linux distribution not shipping ss

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Can it also monitor the statistics, or does it simply read out the statistics of the sockets ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `lsof -i`. You might have to `grep` for the pid you want too look at.